# A Basic Array in javascript, But at end it return NaN while looping through average

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Please consider the following example array of numbers:

```
1, 3 , 2, 5, 8, 32, 4, 5, 9
```

Then consider the following array of numbers generated from the above array by averaging each term with the next:

```
2, 2.5, 3.5, 6.5, 20, 18, 4.5, 7, 9 // last term is the same as itself as there is nothing after it.
```

I have added [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/gimocek/edit?js,console), please check and let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Create a working snippet here itself using `<>`.

Comment: paste your code, not a link... and the link is not even properly visible

Comment: You have: result = (nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2;   Instead, you should use result.push(...      as part of  Array.prototype.push()  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: You really should paste your code to the question, but @anthony-mcgrath answer is correct. You need to use `result.push()` to add to an array.

Comment: Ok guys, This first time i have ever posted anything on stackoverflow. I'll keep in mind next time.@AyushGupta, @gurvinder372

Comment: @SanjeevPratapSingh If your problem is solved, please accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.

Comment: It isn't accepting my upvote... Problem is solved... I'll update with completing other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working correction of your code

```js
function conv (nums) { // nums is the input array of numbers

    var result = [ ] ;

    for(var i=0; i<=nums.length-2; i++)
    {
   
         result.push((nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2); 

      }
    result.push(nums[nums.length-1]);
  

    /* write the code to convert nums array to result */

    return result; // result is the required array of numbers

}

/* this will print an empty array as written. Once you have written your code, the program should produce the correct sample output */
console.log(conv ( [1, 3 , 2, 5, 8, 32, 4, 5, 9] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not adding data to result array.use `push` method to add average to result array.

```js
function conv (nums) { // nums is the input array of numbers

    var result = [ ] ;

    for(var i=0; i<=nums.length-2; i++)
    {
   
         let average = (nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2; 
         result.push(average)

      }
         
  

    /* write the code to convert nums array to result */

    return result; // result is the required array of numbers

}

/* this will print an empty array as written. Once you have written your code, the program should produce the correct sample output */
console.log ( conv ( [1, 3 , 2, 5, 8, 32, 4, 5, 9] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `result` as array and I'm guessing you are expecting `conv` to return array.

You need to chnage this line,

```
result.push = (nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2;
```

to

```
result.push((nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not pushing the *average* to the `result` array

```
function conv(nums) 
{ 
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length - 2; i++) 
  {
    result.push((nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) / 2); //this was missing
  }
  result.push(nums[i]); //push the last element as is
  return result; // result is the required array of numbers
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function conv(nums) { // nums is the input array of numbers
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= nums.length - 2; i++) {
    result.push((nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) / 2);
  }
  result.push(nums[i]);
  return result; // result is the required array of numbers
}

/* this will print an empty array as written. Once you have written your code, the program should produce the correct sample output */
console.log(conv([1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 32, 4, 5, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that you don't have a NaN you should check the both numbers that are used for the averaged are different from **undefined**. Following check should solve your problem:

```
for(var i=0; i<=nums.length-1; i++) {
  if (nums[i+1] === undefined) {
    result [i] = nums[i];
  } else {
    result[i] = (nums[i] + nums[i+1])/2; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push the average to result array and a checkpoint for the last element-

```
function conv(nums) {
        var result = [];    
        for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            i + 1 != nums.length ? result.push((nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) / 2) : result.push(nums[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the average and check if the index exist. If not take the actual element of the array.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 32, 4, 5, 9],
    average = array.map((v, i, a) => (v + a[i + ((i + 1) in a)]) / 2);
    
console.log(average);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```